# Java, how to make variable of the upper class stays null; how to 'hide' variable from the subclass?

Tags: java, subclass, hidden

I have four classes. Class `Person`, and three more, `Student`, `Professor`, `Tutor`, each of which extends class Person. Class Person has 2 variables `studentID` and `staffID`. However, only student can have `studentID != null`, and Tutors and Professors can have `staffID != null`. Now when creating new object Student, how can I make sure that no matter what staffID always stays null? staffID must remain in class Person, so no moving it around.

Comment: Make the variables private, and subclass the setters to enforce the policy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create interfaces to restrict operations:

```
package main;

public interface IsStaff {

    public void setStaffId(Integer staffId);

    public Integer getStaffId();

}



package main;

public interface IsStudent {

    public void setStudentId(Integer studentId);

    public Integer getStudentId();

}
```

Create your Person class:

```
package main;

public class Person {

    protected Integer studentId = null;

    protected Integer staffId = null;

}
```

Create your Student and Staff subclasses with the Interfaces to define the only allowed operations:

```
package main;

public class Staff extends Person implements IsStaff {

    @Override
    public void setStaffId(Integer staffId) {
        this.staffId = staffId;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getStaffId() {
        return staffId;
    }

}



package main;

public class Student extends Person implements IsStudent {

    @Override
    public void setStudentId(Integer studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }

}
```

And now create your Tutors and Professors:

```
package main;

public class Tutor extends Staff {

}


package main;

public class Professor extends Staff {

}
```

Objects of the Student class don't have operations that can affect the staffId, and objects of the Staff class (including the Tutor and Professor subclasses) don't have operations that can affect the studentId.  Add other operations as necessary (common ones can go into Person directly).

As a bonus, you can use the interfaces to better define methods, like this:

```
public void assignParkingSpaceTo(IsStaff staffMember);

public void issueLateSlipTo(IsStudent student);
```

Answer (score 5):

The whole point of inheritance is that only values and functions (members) that are valid for a parent class are placed in the parent class, and any child-specific members are placed in the child class.

Don't abuse OO, move `staffID` into your child class.

My suggestion would be to create a `Staff` class that contains `staffID`, have it inherit `Person`, then have `Professor` and `Tutor` inherit from it. Then move `studentID` into the `Student` class. That way only `Professor` and `Tutor` have access to `staffID` and `Student` does not, and vice versa for `studentID`. All classes can still be assigned to a `Person` type.

Comment: Unfortunately, Tutor is a Student, so tutor actually extends student, and can't extend staff. As a classes the only difference between student and tutor is actually staffID.

Comment: Ok, so scrap the idea of `Staff` and move `staffID` into `Professor`. _Edit: Yay, these upvotes have pushed my rep above 1337!_

Answer (score 1):

The `studentID` should be a member of `Student` not `Person`. Likewise `Professor` and `Tutor` should both extend a class `Faculty` which has a `staffId` which in turn extends `Person`

Answer (score 0):

Make this variables private and create getter and setter.
Depending of class implement different methods behaviors.
For stasfs -  protect setting studentId
for student - protect setting staffId.

Answer (score 0):

don't extend the Person class. Use composition instead.

If you want polymorphism, create a Blammy interface that provides a common interface for Student, Professor, and Tutor.  The student ID and staff Id stuff could or could not be part of the Blammy interface.

Each class, Student, Professor, and Tutor would contain a private instance of Person and proxy to any Person functionality they wanted to expose.

Student would have a studentId data member and Professor and Tutor would have a staffId data member.  The getStudentId() for profesor and tutor would always return null and the get staffId for student would also always return null.

Answer (score 0):

make the variable private, create getters and setters. Then make your constructor initialize both variables, and simple pass null for student ID for teachers, and null for staffID for students.

constructor --->

```
public Person(int staffID, int studentID){
this.staffID = staffID;
this.studentID = studentID:
}
```

when you initialize ---->

```
 Student student = new Person(null, 1234);
```